# MonetDB, data loss in restart server

Tags: monetdb, data-loss

I have been using MonetDB in production for some time now, and I have nothing to complain about.
My database has tables with more than 30 columns and 30 million records, and I perform analysis through cubes in Pentaho / Saiku.
I have restarted the server several times before, and never had any problem with data loss. However, after running a query today that was consuming a lot of resources, I decided to stop the database, and when I restarted it, data from some columns have disappeared. How can that happen? Were the data still uncommitted?
I am concerned that running the query in MonetDB has changed the data or reorganised the database.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't double-post here and on the MonetDB mailing list. Our support resources are scarce. The data are not reorganized if you are simply running a SQL query. I would suspect other issues such as a hard disk running out of free space or file system corruption.

Comment: First sorry for posts !!
I also thought of disk failure and even can be, but there is also this report (https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2009-July/003253.html), has to be?

Comment: That issue appeared on an ancient version and was fixed way back. The only way we can do something about this is if you find a reproducible example. Also, check your database directory, there should be a file called merovingian.log. See if any errors are in there.